# How can I convert PICT format file on Big Sur

Tags: big-sur, file-conversion

I have an old Keynote file that contains a PICT-formatted picture from my 2007 archive, which I want to use now.

Keynote refuses to convert it. Is there any way I can convert into any newer format on Big Sur?

Comment: Open in Keynote then do a screengrab? Open in preview and export as?

Answer (score 1):

Try [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter) which has a free demo.

I can't find a list of supported file types on their page, but I've yet to find anything it can't handle.

After comments, I downloaded a test .pict file from https://filesamples.com/formats/pict to see what could open it.

[image]

I tested a handful of these & all were successful.
Perhaps there's an issue with your image file.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like GraphicsConverted tried to open it, figured picture dimension correctly, but it can't show the preview. bad luck. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @shigeya - see the update to my answer. I had no issues opening a pict in most of the apps listed.

Answer (score 1):

For converting image files, [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org) is usually a good choice. It [supports PICT](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/formats.html). You can install it via Homebrew:

```
brew install graphicsmagick
```

To convert a file, call `gm convert <input> <output>`, the format is usually auto-detected using the file extension. [See the manual](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html) for options.

Comment: Thanks. I've totally forgotten about it. So give it a try, and found that it does not accept PICT. :< I've tested with "GraphicsMagick 1.3.36 20201226 Q16" latest with homebrew

Comment: But as you wrote its supports the format. I will check the manual.